# Read Gmail inbox via RSS Feed

Tags: asp.net

I want to get Inbox via RSS, I can get XML when I use Response.Redirect , but can not get as XML format, it throws (401) unauthorized error My Code is

```
    string url = "https://myusername:mypassword@mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom";
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url);
    SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
    reader.Close();
```

-->Response.redirect(url); //it is working
Can any one have any idea about it,
or 
is any verson of AE.Net.Mail.dll for Framework 2.0

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XmlReader` class cannot parse authentication information from the URL, you have to create an `XmlSettings` instance and set its `XmlResolver` property to an `XmlUrlResolver` instance that has its credentials set to the username and password. Then when you create the `XmlReader` instance, you supply the custom `XmlSettings` instance. The following code would do the trick:

```
// Create a resolver with your credentials
XmlUrlResolver resolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
resolver.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword");

// Set the reader settings object to use the resolver.
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.XmlResolver = resolver;

string url = "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom";

// Create the reader using the specified URL and settings
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url, settings);

SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
reader.Close();
```

However, I tried this code and the following `XmlException` was thrown:
*"The element with name 'feed' and namespace 'http://purl.org/atom/ns#' is not an allowed feed format."*

It appears that the feeds Google outputs are in a format that is incompatible with the `SyndicationFeed` class. For more information see: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/csharp/9faa101f-0a1a-465f-a41a-3e52dd9f7526/everything-rss--atom-feed-parser.aspx

Comment: Thanks for Helping, It worked for me, Finally I ignored Syndicate and read data from direct reader..